# List the names of people that have never scored above 3

Tags: sql

From a table like this:

```
Name   | Score
------ | ------
Bill   | 1  
Bill   | 2
Bill   | 1
Steve  | 1 
Steve  | 4 
Steve  | 1
```

Return the names of people that have never scored above 3

Answer would be:

```
Name   | 
------ | 
Bill   |
```

Comment: @DanieleO you have a major problem with your *base sql query*.

Comment: @scott have a look on posted queries

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to get the maximum score for each person, then filter to those whose maximum is less than 3. To get the maximum you need to do an aggregate (`GROUP BY` and `MAX`). Then to apply filters to aggregates you must use `HAVING` rather than `WHERE`. So you would end up with:

```
SELECT Name, MAX(Score) AS HighScore
FROM Table 
GROUP BY Name 
HAVING MAX(Score) <= 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

one solution would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
  FROM mytable 
 WHERE Name NOT IN 
        ( SELECT Name 
            FROM mytable 
           WHERE score > 3
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name 
FROM table_name
WHERE score < 3
```

Answer (score 0):

**sample table** :

```
DECLARE @Table1  TABLE 
    (Name varchar(5), Score int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (Name, Score)
VALUES
    ('Bill', 1),
    ('Bill', 2),
    ('Bill', 1),
    ('Steve', 1),
    ('Steve', 4),
    ('Steve', 1)
;
```

**Script** :

```
;with CTE AS (
select Name,Score from @Table1
GROUP BY Name,Score
HAVING (Score) > 3 )
Select 
NAME,
Score  
from  @Table1 T 
where not EXISTS 
(select name from CTE 
        where name = T.Name )
```

**Result** :

```
NAME    Score
Bill    1
Bill    2
Bill    1
```

Comment: this solution seems to be a little "overkill", isn't it?

Comment: lot of ways every one have their own thoughts .Stack overflow is name for that one problem different solutions @EstebanP.Questioner will have lot of options to choose

Comment: sorry, shouldn't sound like the solution is wrong. i just thought "wow, thats like taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut" ;-)